# I tried to run this "composer require mckenziearts/laravel-notify" in my laravel 6 project but I get this error

Tags: composer-php, laravel-6

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires laravel/tinker ^2.0, found laravel/tinker[v2.0.0, ..., 2.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v1.0.10 (lock file version) by
a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
Problem 2
- mckenziearts/laravel-notify 2.x-dev requires illuminate/support ~7.0 -> found illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- mckenziearts/laravel-notify v2.1 requires illuminate/support ^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires mckenziearts/laravel-notify ^2.1 -> satisfiable by mckenziearts/laravel-notify[v2.1, 2.x-dev].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

### This is the composer.json file. laravel 6.

I think there's an update for me to do but I don't know where to do that.

{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
"framework",
"laravel"
],

```
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
},

"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "laravel/ui": "^1.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
},

"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},

"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},

"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },

    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},

"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},

"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],

    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],

    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Please share more details, like the current state of your `composer.json` and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: I have added the composer.json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Laravel v6 and try to install `mckenziearts/laravel-notify` in the most recent version, which is only compatible with Laravel v7 and v8.

You should either upgrade Laravel, or install `mckenziearts/laravel-notify` in v1 through `composer require mckenziearts/laravel-notify "^1.0"`